# how to cancel subscribes or notification in chef cookbook recipes?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, subscribe, recipe

I run into a question here:
for example, the chef cookbook recipe is openstack-network::openvswitch

```
service 'neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent' do
  service_name platform_options['neutron_openvswitch_agent_service']
  supports status: true, restart: true
  action :enable
  subscribes :restart, 'template[/etc/neutron/neutron.conf]'
end
```

What I want to do here is to cancel the subscribes of the service 'neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent'. I looked the Chef::Resource doc , but I cannot find this kind of API.
In a ruby_block, I can use

```
resources('service[neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent').action(:nothing)
```

to change a resource'action before the action is apply on the resource, so Is there any way to cancel a resource's subscribe or even notifies?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use chef-rewind's `unwind` helper. In general this isn't an easy thing to do, notifications don't live in the resource object, they are part of the run context data.